# Proving the existence of a sequence of functions converging to 0 with an added property

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

This is a problem from Rudin's Functional Analysis:

Show that there is a sequence of functions $\{ f_n \}$ in $X$ (the vector space of all complex functions) such that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, but if any sequence $\{ \gamma_n \}$ tends to $\infty$, $\gamma_n f_n \not\to 0$.

The hint says to use the fact that the collections of all complex sequences converging to $0$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$. Honestly, this confused me more than it helped me.

My main issue is through the method of showing existence: I am not sure if I should attempt to construct an explicit sequence $f_n$, or if I need to appeal to other nonconstructive means such as Zorn's Lemma, etc. I have been trying to construct clever choices of sequences for a good bit now, but it always seems like I will be able to find a sequence that diverges slowly enough to allow that $\gamma_n f_n \to 0$.

Thanks!

Comment: Where in the book is this exercise?

Comment: Chapter 1, problem 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the hint, we can define a function $f:\mathbb{N}\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ such that for each sequence $\{z_n\}$ of complex numbers convergent to $0$, there exists $t\in[0,1]$ such that 
$$ f(n,t)=z_n $$
for all $n$. Define $\{f_n\}$ by $f_n(t)=f(n,t)$.

Now let $\{\gamma_n\}$ be some sequence tending towards $\infty$ (without loss of generality, suppose $\gamma_n\neq0$ for all $n$).  Then $\frac{1}{\gamma_n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, and there is some $t_0\in[0,1]$ with 
$$ f_n(t_0)=f(n,t_0)=\frac{1}{\gamma_n}$$
for all $n$.  Thus, we have
$f_n(t_0)\gamma_n=1$
for all $n$, and therefore $\gamma_nf_n$ does not tend towards $0$.

Comment: Beautifully clever. Thanks!